# Problem installing PyQtChart module in python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt

I am trying to install the PyQtChart module for embedded graphics in PyQt5, for this I do the traditional procedure:

1. windows + R
2. pip install PyQtChart

The problem is that when doing so, I get the following errors, and the module is not installed, attached image:

[image]

For my works I use the editor 'Spyder', which comes when I install anaconda.
If someone has had a similar problem or knows how to solve this type of problem, I would greatly appreciate it, kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have to have the same version of PyQt5 and PyQtChart installed:**

```
python -m pip install PyQt5==5.15 PyQtChart==5.15
```

**Also, try to install from windows power shell(admin) mode**

Comment: Thank you very much for your contributions, indeed, the versions must be the same, but it is also important to install in this way, at least it worked for me: `pip install --user PyQtChart == 5.12`, (In my case I opted for versions 5.12.), best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that the version of PyQtChart is the same that PyQt5:

```
python -m pip install PyQt5==5.13 PyQtChart==5.13
```